# Expected Cost while gambling

Tags: probability

It cost \$35 to gamble for the golden idol. There is a 1% chance that you'll get it, and a 99% chance that you'll get a common household item. Each gambler can own at most one golden idol, and unlimited common household items. Pulling a common household item does not affect the chances of getting another one in the future.

So, suppose every gambler is determined to spend money until they get that idol (and you can't acquire it anywhere other than this gambling game... for some reason). **How much would you expect the average gambler is going to spend in order to obtain the idol (they stop gambling once they get it)**?

I came at this from two angles, and I can't sort out which (if either) is right. First, I think that if there's a 1% chance and costs \$35, then I would think the average spent per person to simply be \$3500.

Alternatively, I could see that there's a 99% chance to not get the golden idol, so $1 - (.99 ^ {69})$ would yield roughly \$2,415 in order to have a 50% chance of getting 1 or more idol (though, obviously, you couldn't actually get more than 1).

Any thoughts on which approach is correct, including potentially a third one I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is correct, and your intuitive reason is correct although it is not a proof.

The expected amount you would pay is given by $$\sum_n (\text{cost of trying }n\text{ times}\times\text{probability that it takes }n\text{ tries})$$

$$=\sum_n (35n)\times(.99^{n-1}\times.01)$$

Which does in fact simplify to 3500. The computations are a bit long and messy so I'll link you to [this page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Geometric_Distribution) for more details.

Comment: I've gone ahead and selected this answer, as it appears correct to the best of my ability to determine such. If you don't mind, could you prove why my second approach is wrong? What does the 2415 number actually mean, then?

Comment: Expectation is an average, weighted by probability, like the summations I wrote above. When you compute the number of tries you need to have a 50% chance of getting an idol, the expected number of idols you will have by that point is in fact more than $\frac{1}{2}$, since you could have no idols (50% chance), 1 idol, 2 idols, etc. So the number of rounds you need to play in order to have a 50% chance is not the same as the expected number of rounds you need to play.

Comment: That sounds pretty reasonable to me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Another(?) approach: With $n\gg 0$ rounds, we will satisfy approximately $0.01n$ gamblers, so to satisfyall $N$ gamblers, we need about $100N$ rounds at a cost of $\$3500N$